# How to embed iframe without breaking floated layout?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm embedding a YT video (iframe) within my floated layout and it's breaking the float. The right div complete disappears from view.

Its a simple layout:

---

|content| left | middle | right | /content |

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BMXBX/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle">
        <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="200" height="180" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/CTAud5O7Qqk?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" />
    </div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
width: 100%;
background-color: gray;
height: 200px;
}
#left {
width: 25%;
height: 190px;
background-color: green;
float: left;
}
#middle {
height: 190px;
width: 50%;
background-color: purple;
float: left;
}
#right {
width: 25%;
height: 190px;
background-color: orange;
float: left;
}
#content {
width: 80%;
height: 200px;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: It's funny but dragonfly shows me fiddle doesn't even output last (right) div in case there is `iframe` in center (I mean this div is not presented at all in source of output we see on their site).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't closed the iframe correctly with the required `</iframe>`

http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/vkhse/

Comment: nice catch. didnt even realize. was trying to play with css.

Comment: np dude. Happens to us all :-)

Comment: I grabbed the code from here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player which doesn't close the iframe??

Comment: @bengem interesting. they must have forgotten to put it there. when you click share and select embed on youtube it gives you closing tag properly.

Comment: Submitted a bug report, hopefully they'll fix

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems with your markup:

1. The `<iframe>` is not closed correctly.
2. The `#container` div is not closed (but it might be that you did not copy the last line).
3. The `type` attribute for `<iframe>` does not exist.
4. The `frameborder` attribute is deprecated: use CSS.

If you need to embed a YT video, then simply click on Share, then Embedded HTML under a video.

Comment: Thanks, the missing closing tag was the fundamental issue. I'd copied it from the google dev documentation which seems to be incorrect.. https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's still having problems even with the closing tag, try sticking something in between the tags, eg: `<iframe>&nbsp;</iframe>`

(Worked for me.)